# How can I convert the time in a datetime string from 24:00 to 00:00 in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

I have a lot of date strings like `Mon, 16 Aug 2010 24:00:00` and some of them are in `00-23` hour format and some of them in `01-24` hour format. I want to get a list of date objects of them, but when I try to transform the example string into a date object, I have to transform it from `Mon, 16 Aug 2010 24:00:00` to `Tue, 17 Aug 2010 00:00:00`. What is the easiest way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import email.utils as eutils
import time
import datetime

ntuple=eutils.parsedate('Mon, 16 Aug 2010 24:00:00')
print(ntuple)
# (2010, 8, 16, 24, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1)
timestamp=time.mktime(ntuple)
print(timestamp)
# 1282017600.0
date=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
print(date)
# 2010-08-17 00:00:00
print(date.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S'))
# Tue, 17 Aug 2010 00:00:00
```

Since you say you have a lot of these to fix, you should define a function:

```
def standardize_date(date_str):
    ntuple=eutils.parsedate(date_str)
    timestamp=time.mktime(ntuple)
    date=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
    return date.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')

print(standardize_date('Mon, 16 Aug 2010 24:00:00'))
# Tue, 17 Aug 2010 00:00:00
```

Comment: +1 because I never even knew `email.utils.parsedate()` existed until now and learning is fun!

Comment: Yes, I learned about `email.utils.parsedate` here on SO too... :)

Comment: Not sure if files are ever time-stamped with leap seconds, but there can be up to 86402 seconds in a day (though usually just 86401 when needed). (time can go `Mon, 16 Aug 24:00:01` to  `Tue, 17 Aug 00:00:00`)

Comment: Leap-seconds aside, though, 24:00:00 is a perfectly acceptable time stamp (ISO 8601 [2004], §4.2.3: ‘Midnight’) and is widely used in data logging. It means that the last record at the end of the day is still marked as belonging to that day. It prevents off-by-one errors in aggregate functions.