# How can I convert WIQL query output into a structured data frame?

Tags: python, dataframe, azure-devops

I have managed to connect to Azure DevOps via their API (thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52810441/how-to-extract-workitems-from-query-in-vsts-azure-devops-with-python-rest-api) that was raised) , and managed to get the output required detailing all work items recorded. However, I would like to convert the output into a dataframe.

```
def print_work_items(work_items):
    for work_item in work_items:
        print(
            "{0} {1}: {2}".format(
                work_item.fields["System.WorkItemType"],
                work_item.id,
                work_item.fields["System.Title"],
            )
        )


wit_client = connection.clients.get_work_item_tracking_client()


def get_TC_from_query(query):
    query_wiql = Wiql(query=query)
    results = wit_client.query_by_wiql(query_wiql).work_items
    # WIQL query gives a WorkItemReference => we get the corresponding WorkItem from id
    work_items = (wit_client.get_work_item(int(result.id)) for result in results)
    #print_work_items(work_items)
   
    
dq_workitems = get_TC_from_query(
    """\
        SELECT
                [System.Id],
                [System.WorkItemType],
                [System.Title],
                [System.State],
                [System.AreaPath],
                [System.AssignedTo]
        FROM workitems
        WHERE
                [System.AreaPath] = 'Designated Area Path'
        ORDER BY [System.Id] DESC
        """
        )


df = pd.DataFrame(print_work_items(dq_workitems), columns=['Id','WorkItemType','Title',
                                         'State','AreaPath','AssignedTo']) 
print(df)
```

I am able to print out the work items onto the console but fail to populate the dataframe. Any thoughts/leads would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following steps worked for me:

- I converted each row to a data frame.
- concatenated the list of data frames.
- exported the list as a CSV.

```
work_items = (
    wit_client.get_work_item(int(res.id)) for res in wiql_results
)
workitems_df_list: List[DataFrame] = []

for work_item in work_items:
    row = "{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6}".format(
        work_item.id,
        work_item.fields["System.TeamProject"],
        work_item.fields["System.WorkItemType"],
        work_item.fields["System.Title"],
        work_item.fields["System.State"],
        work_item.fields["Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority"],
        work_item.fields["System.CreatedDate"]
    )
    workitems_df_list.append(pd.DataFrame(list(reader([row]))))

workitems_final_df = pd.concat(workitems_df_list)
workitems_final_df.to_csv(r'C:\test\workitems_test.csv', sep=',')
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try to write Wiql query output to a `.csv` file first, and then convert the csv file to data frame.

Write to `.csv` file:

```
# Create the csv file
with open('vehicle.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_handle:
    writer = csv.writer(f_handle)
    # Add the header/column names
    header = ['id', 'Title', 'State', 'WorkItemType']
    writer.writerow(header)
    # Iterate over `data`  and  write to the csv file
    for row in data:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

[Convert csv file to dataframe](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-convert-a-%60.csv%60-file-to-a-pandas-dataframe-in-python):

Use `pd.read_csv()` to convert a .csv file to a pandas dataframe.

Call `pd.read_csv(file)` with the path name of a .csv file as file to return a DataFrame with the .csv data.

Here are some reference you can refer to:

- [query output to .csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47107717/sql-query-output-to-csv/47112458)
- [Python converting csv files to dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53227868/python-converting-csv-files-to-dataframes)
- [Convert csv file to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514046/convert-csv-file-to-pandas-dataframe)