# Get nearest time value and convert format

Tags: python, pandas

I am building a telegram bot which given a geographical position will return the time the next buses will leave from the nearest stop. Now, I am having a problem with the time format and I don't know how to efficiently find the nearest time value.

In pandas I loaded the following file (I deleted some irrelevant info):

```
                         trip_id arrival_time departure_time ...
4444   0...07     24:00:00       24:00:00       79   
11735  0...07     24:00:00       24:00:00       65   
24122  0...07     24:00:00       24:00:00      192   
45251  0...07     24:00:00       24:00:00      236
```

python's datetime library only handles time in `0..23` format and so does pandas `.to_datetime()` function. Now the columns are loaded as strings.

I could of course do a regex substitution and convert the time in `00:` format but I was wandering if there is proper way to do it since I might want to do the same operation in other files.

Then, given the proper format and the time of the request, is there a way to get only the rows following the given time.

i.e. given 07:35, how to get only the rows starting from 07:35 on (07:36...) ?

Comment: What string do you want to convert to a time? `'24:00:00'`? Would that be midnight? Can you provide other examples?

Comment: Yes, I have a whole bunch of '24:01:00','24:02:00','24:07:00' and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Slicing**: In order to select a slice in the way you asked, you could use a mask:

```
mask = df['arrival_time'] > '07:35:00'
# then work on df[mask]
```

Or if you set the time as index, you can use regular Python-type slicing:

```
df.set_index('arrival_time', inplace=True)
df['07:35:00':]
```

**Time conversion**: In order to convert your strings to time, you could use the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3493966/5276797

If you do convert your strings to time however, slicing would have to change a bit. Something like the code below:

```
from datetime import datetime
mask = df['arrival_time'] > datetime(2016, 2, 15, 7, 35)  # now you need a date
```