# Converting string 1-24 to datetime format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-datetime

I have a dataset (simulation output) with a timestamp as follows:
|Date/Time | BLOCK1:BEDROOM:Zone Operative Temperature C|
|----------|---------------------------------------------------------|
|01:00:00  |23.8|
|02:00:00  |23.6|
|03:00:00  |23.2|
|03:00:00  |23.2|
|03:00:00  |23.2|
|03:00:00  |23.2|
|03:00:00  |23.2|
|03:00:00  |23.2|
|03:00:00  |23.2|
|24:00:00  |23.7|

This is just an example. I have 365 days of output. I am trying to convert this to DateTime format using the following code:

```
data2['Date/Time'] = pd.to_datetime(data2['Date/Time'], format = '%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
time data '01/01  24:00:00' does not match format '%m/%d %H:%M:%S' (match)
```

I would really appreciate it if I get help on this.

I tried the ways mentioned in the following link but they are not working for my case:
[How can I convert the time in a datetime string from 24:00 to 00:00 in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493924/how-can-i-convert-the-time-in-a-datetime-string-from-2400-to-0000-in-python)

Comment: Looks like there are two whitespaces? So `'%m/%d  %H:%M:%S'`

Comment: That is because 1 second after `01-01 23:59:59`, it is `01-02 00:00:00`, there is no `24:00:00` in that day, you would have to tell us what do you expect for such cases..!!

Comment: No there is only one white space

Comment: @anky, But my dataset does have 24:00:00. And this is a simulation output so I do not have any control over timestamp generated out of the software

Comment: @anky, each day starts at 01:00:00 as shown in the image above.

Comment: How do you want to deal with this value? If you just want to ignore it, you can use `data2['Date/Time'] = pd.to_datetime(data2['Date/Time'], format = '%m/%d %H:%M:%S', errors='ignore')`

Comment: Should the last hour `24:00:00` be treated as next day or the same day? if the later what time should it contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@anky is correct that 24:00:00 should be 00:00:00.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(['01/01 01:00:00', '01/01 24:00:00'], columns = ['Date/Time'])
df['Date/Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time'], format='%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
print(df)
```

throws this error:

```
ValueError: time data '01/01 24:00:00' does not match format '%m/%d %H:%M:%S' (match)
```

One way to fix this is to replace 24:00:00 with 00:00:00.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(['01/01 01:00:00', '01/01 24:00:00'], columns = ['Date/Time'])
df['Date/Time'] = df['Date/Time'].replace({'24:00:00': '00:00:00'}, regex=True)
print(df)

        Date/Time
0  01/01 01:00:00
1  01/01 00:00:00
```

Another way would be to ignore the error.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(['01/01 01:00:00', '01/01 24:00:00'], columns = ['Date/Time'])
df['Date/Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time'], format='%m/%d %H:%M:%S', errors='ignore')
print(df)

        Date/Time
0  01/01 01:00:00
1  01/01 24:00:00
```

Personally, I would add a year to the date/time column.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(['01/01 01:00:00', '01/01 24:00:00'], columns = ['Date/Time'])
df['Date/Time'] = df['Date/Time'].replace({'24:00:00': '00:00:00'}, regex=True)
df['Date/Time'] = pd.to_datetime('2020-' + df['Date/Time'])
print(df)

           Date/Time
0 2020-01-01 01:00:00
1 2020-01-01 00:00:00
```